# Using interpolation in statistics

Tags: statistics

[image]

For part "d" of this question , it requires the number of days the maximum gust was in the interval [16.08 , 30.72] which lies in the $2^{nd}$ , $3^{rd}$ , $4^{th}$ and $5^{th}$ classes . I can find the answer by eliminating the frequencies of the $1^{st}$ and the last class from the total frequency to get the number of days to be $47$

Is this answer correct ? And how can i find the answer using interpolation ?

Answer (score 1):

**Estimating Sample Mean and Standard Deviation from a Histogram**

***Assuming data at bin centers.*** In such cases one often assumes, as an approximation, that all $f_i$ observations falling into interval $i$ with midpoint $m_i$ are located at the midpoint. Then the sample
mean $A$ is estimated as $A = \bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^K f_im_i,$ where $K$ is the number of intervals and $n = \sum_{i=1}^K f_.$

Then the sample variance $V = S^2$ can be estimated as
$$V = S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^K f_i(m_i-A)^2,$$
so that the sample standard deviation is estimated as $S = \sqrt{V}.$

For your table, my approximations for (c) are obtained (using R as a calculator) as follows:

```
f = c(3,9,9,20,9,7)
m = c(12.5,16.5,19,22.5,27.5,40)
n = sum(f);  n
[1] 57
a = sum(f*m)/n;  a
[1] 23.41228
v = sum(f*(m-a)^2)/(n-1)
s = sqrt(v);  s
[1] 7.386718
```

(d) You seek the number of observations in the interval $A \pm S$ or $(16,31).$

```
pm = c(-1,1);  a + pm*s
[1] 16.02556 30.79900
```

***Assuming data evenly spread within intervals.*** Now assuming observations to be evenly spread within their respective intervals,
that means about half of interval $[15,18),$ all of the next three intervals, and perhaps
a small piece of $[30,50).$ That gives approximately $4.5 + 9 + 20  + 9 + .3 = 42.8 \approx 43$ of the $n = 57$ observations within $A \pm S.$

```
4.5 + 9 + 20  + 9 + .3
[1] 42.8
```

***Assuming data are normal.*** Assuming that the population of maximum wind gusts is *approximately normal* one can find that about 68.3% of its observations within one standard deviation from the mean.
That would estimate about $57(0.683) \approx 39$ observations, compared with our
sample estimate of $42.8.$ However, with only $n=57$ observations we should not
expect much closer agreement. And you said nothing about normality in your question.

```
p.c = diff(pnorm(c(-1,1))); p.c
[1] 0.6826895
p.c*n
[1] 38.9133
```

*Notes:* (1) You have not shown or specified anything about 'linear interpolation', so what
your instructor or text author has in mind might be somewhat different from what I showed above.

(2) Also,
I have guessed that the wind gust measurements are given to a few decimal places
so that, for example, the length of interval $[15,18)$ is essentially $3$ with
midpoint $15.4.$ If you assume measurements are rounded to integers, then
$[15,18)$ has length $2$ and center $16.$

(3) Making tables and histograms with capriciously chosen different interval
widths is not good statistical practice. I have no idea what style of histogram       you may be using in your course. Below is a dataset simulated with the
designated bin counts and a 'density' histogram in R (in which the sum of the areas of the bars is $1).$ The exact sample mean and standard deviation for
my simulated sample are $A = 23.1, S = 7.08,$ respectively. These are not
far from the estimates derived above for your table. For these simulated
data the number of observations in $A \pm S$ is $45.$

[image]

```
set.seed(1234)
x =c(runif( 3,10,15),runif(9,15,18),runif(9,18,20), 
     runif(20,20,25),runif(9,25,30),runif(7,30,50))
hist(x, br=c(10,15,18,20,25,30,50), col="wheat"); rug(x)
a = mean(x); s = sd(x)
a; s
[1] 23.0535
[1] 7.076149
sum((x > a-s) & (x < a+s))
[1] 45
```